# Create random ball tile animation

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making this tile using `createGraphics` and a `for` loop. Is there any way that I can make the random ball start in a different position in each tile?

Here is the code that I've tried:

```js
let graphics;
let x;
let y;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  pixelDensity(1);
  graphics=createGraphics(200,200);
  graphics.background(255,0,0);
  x=graphics.width/2;
  y=graphics.height/2;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  for ( let i=0; i<width; i+=200){
    for ( let j=0; j<height; j+=200){    
      image(graphics,i,j);  
      graphics.fill(0);
      graphics.strokeWeight(2);
      graphics.stroke(255,0,0);
      graphics.ellipse(x+i,y+j,10);
      
      x+=random(-5,5);
      y+=random(-5,5);
  
      if ( x<0 || x > graphics.width){
        x=graphics.width/2;
      }
  
      if ( y<0 || y > graphics.height){
        y=graphics.height/2;
      }  
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your current code only has one x and y. You'll need to create an array of 4 x and y objects, like `const balls = [{x: 42, y: 42}, {x: 1, y: 6}, ...]`, then loop over the array in `draw()` and render each tile specific to that ball's x and y using your current logic using `balls[index].x` and `balls[index].y` rather than your current loose `x` and `y`. Once that's working, add random numbers instead of hardcoding the positions.

Comment: Did you _intend_ to render both your off-screen graphics and the main sketch at the same time? Because you don't have "tiles" here, you have a single off-screen canvas that you're drawing things on, and then you treat that canvas as an image and draw it on top of your sketch inside your inner loops (which you don't want: you want to draw your off-screen frame first, and then use a single `image(graphics,0,0)` after your nested loop is done to update the screen)